# How to start with Programming in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

So far I have worked with C Programming and C++ Programming. I am fairly new to DOT NET environment and my current project requires VB.Net skills. I need to know

1)Which books to refer for starting with VB.Net language?
2)How to Start with VB.Net Programming?
3)Are there any forums/articles for quick head start.

Thanks in advance to all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After mastering c/c++, VB.NET will be easy for you.

**Where to start:**

[MSDN Visual Basic Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4wf33f0.aspx), specialy the *Visual Basic Language Features*, and *Program Structure and Code Conventions*.

**Forums / Articles:**

- Stackoverflow has lots of .NET experts, ask anything and you shell be answered! :)
- http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/
- [Visual Basic Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789074)

Since VB.NET and C# are both .NET languages, almost all code written in C# can be easily converted to VB.  From my personal experience, C# is more widely spread and I often find myself [converting](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) C# code samples to VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# is similar to C, you could start by looking at this

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

To help you how to write VB. Then it's just a matter of learning the framework classes.

You could also look at the ".NET Framework Class Library" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx to give you a quick list of every namespace/class available.